# Android: Temporarily pairing two smartphones with Bluetooth with one permission

Tags: android, security, permissions, bluetooth

I'm developing an app that will exchange a tiny bit of data (<30 bytes) between two Android devices. I've decided to use Bluetooth, because my project requires: medium distance between devices (~5m) and not being dependent on the Internet.
   The problem is, a single device could participate in a *couple hundred* mentioned exchanges every day. Bluetooth requires a permission to pair devices (BLUETOOTH_ADMIN), which - when done a couple hunder times a day - is really terrible, but is there a way to ask for a permission just once? Something like "This application will pair you with other devices and exchange data with them. Do you agree?" and from here the app can exchange the data with other users of the app freely. Ideally, I want to achieve the BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED state after recieving the users approval.
   Perhaps, I shouldn't use Bluetooth for this kind of thing? The exchange doesn't even need to be secure. It just needs to know what device it's supposed to go to and contain the 30 bytes of data. After the exchange the devices unpair and go their own ways.